# heater wire 120v 2-wire. one side ribbed and the other white writing?

Tags: wiring, radiant-heating

i tried to add a photo but my phone cant seem to compress the image small enuff..so..this cord turns logic on its head..one side is continuous ribbing while the other has white printing on it..so i have a cord that by all quoted standards is two neutral wires sided by side with no third wire or hot wire (at least not one that plays by the rules) ..two wires...heater..one ribbed...the other white writing stating voltage and temp...on a 1200watt radiant heater..no plug end and its glued together at the seams.. so whats really goin on? i wanna guess the ribbed is neutral but thats a fools venture if i am mistaken...

Answer (score 2):

The ribbed side is the neutral (actually called grounded conductor, not to be confused with the equipment grounding conductor).

NEC 400.22 Grounded-Conductor Identification. One conductor of flexible cords that is intended to be used as a grounded circuit conductor shall have a continuous marker that readily distinguishes it from the other conductor or conductors. The identification shall consist of one of the methods indicated in 400.22(A) through (F).

(F)Surface Marking. One or more ridges, grooves, or white stripes located on the exterior of the cord so as to identify one conductor for cords having insulation on the individual conductors integral with the jacket.